# Validation of date field using jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am new to `jQuery`. How can I validate a date field?

The date entered must be the current date, or a date before the current date. How can I do this without disabling future dates in the date picker?

Comment: "Date Picker" which date picker? And what do you really have done or you are just thinking about.... :)

Comment: He has the jQuery UI datepicker as a tag

Comment: I can only see Jquery and Validation from here

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code to validate your date in javascript.

```
var selectedDate = $("#yourDate").val();
var currentDate = new Date();

if(new Date(selectedDate) > currentDate){
   alert("Invalid Date");
}
```

Comment: The Question isn't just how to validate date rather with reference to "Date Picker"

Comment: you can disable dates, but you mentioned you want to validate it rather than disabling them in calender.

Comment: Its left for the person that asked!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for that, as ist is just JavaScript:

```
 var now = new date();
 var inDate = .... // wherever you get it from, 

 if ( inDate > now )
 {
     // error handling
 }
 else
     // proceed with valid date
```

Date Objects can be compared directly with operators like `== <= >= < >` in JavaScript

Comment: and whats wrong with that which deserves a downvote?

Comment: Cite: "**How can I do this** without disabling future dates in the date picker" and it refers to the date comparison, not the picker.

Comment: please I noticed that my upvote didnt commit. Can you make help make a change so that I can commit the up vote as that is a requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
var userDateString = '2014/03/01'; // this can be the value from the date picker

var userDate = new Date(userDateString);
var nowDate = Date.now();

if (userDate.getTime() <= nowDate) {
    console.log("User's date is less than or equal to today's date.");
} else {
    console.log("User's date is greater than today's date.");
}
```

JSBin example:

**http://jsbin.com/zohiki/1/edit**